# How to make the Flashing Button appear after the text

Tags: html, css

I have a simple HTML problem. I have a text and a css button.

My problem is I want to make the css button appear right after my text.

here is my HTML:-

```html
    <style>
    .led-box {
    height: 30px;
    width: 25%;
    margin: 10px 0;
    float: left;
    }

    .led-box p {
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 1em;
    }

    .led-red {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    background-color: #F00;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0 -1px 7px 1px, inset #441313 0 -1px 9px, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5) 0 2px 12px;
  -webkit-animation: blinkRed 0.5s infinite;
  -moz-animation: blinkRed 0.5s infinite;
  -ms-animation: blinkRed 0.5s infinite;
  -o-animation: blinkRed 0.5s infinite;
  animation: blinkRed 0.5s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes blinkRed {
    from { background-color: #F00; }
    50% { background-color: #A00; box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0 -1px 7px 1px, inset #441313 0 -1px 9px, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5) 0 2px 0;}
    to { background-color: #F00; }
}
@-moz-keyframes blinkRed {
    from { background-color: #F00; }
    50% { background-color: #A00; box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0 -1px 7px 1px, inset #441313 0 -1px 9px, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5) 0 2px 0;}
    to { background-color: #F00; }
}
@-ms-keyframes blinkRed {
    from { background-color: #F00; }
    50% { background-color: #A00; box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0 -1px 7px 1px, inset #441313 0 -1px 9px, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5) 0 2px 0;}
    to { background-color: #F00; }
}
@-o-keyframes blinkRed {
    from { background-color: #F00; }
    50% { background-color: #A00; box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0 -1px 7px 1px, inset #441313 0 -1px 9px, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5) 0 2px 0;}
    to { background-color: #F00; }
}
@keyframes blinkRed {
    from { background-color: #F00; }
    50% { background-color: #A00; box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0 -1px 7px 1px, inset #441313 0 -1px 9px, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5) 0 2px 0;}
    to { background-color: #F00; }
}
</style>
    <div class="row"></div>

    <h1 class="center" style="color:Black; font-size: 3.5vw;">Welcome to <span id="h5">Comet 1.1</span></h1>
       
    <div class="led-box">
        <div class="led-red"></div>
        <p>Request Pending</p>
    </div>
```

The image below is my output:-

[image]

I have now edited by code please have a look and let me know what can be the possible solution.

Comment: You gave a little code. Where is your css?

Comment: Share the full code along with the CSS. On the above code, don't have the background image.

Comment: I have edited my code. you can skip the background image as I don't think its a problem. but yes now please suggest how can I make my flashing button appear after the welcome message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added div with `.textContainer` class which wraps text & <kbd>button</kbd>. Also removed `float: left` css property.

**[Codepen Example](https://codepen.io/cursorrux/pen/RwGLzbG)**

***Code snippet:***

```css
.led-box {
    height: 30px;
    width: 25%;
    margin: 10px 0;
    display: inline-block;
}

.led-box p {
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 1em;
}

.led-red {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    background-color: #F00;
    border-radius: 50%; 
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0 -1px 7px 1px, inset #441313 0 -1px 9px, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5) 0 2px 12px;
    -webkit-animation: blinkRed 0.5s infinite;
    -moz-animation: blinkRed 0.5s infinite;
    -ms-animation: blinkRed 0.5s infinite;
    -o-animation: blinkRed 0.5s infinite;
    animation: blinkRed 0.5s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes blinkRed {
    from { background-color: #F00; }
    50% { background-color: #A00; box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0 -1px 7px 1px, inset #441313 0 -1px 9px, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5) 0 2px 0;}
    to { background-color: #F00; }
}
@-moz-keyframes blinkRed {
    from { background-color: #F00; }
    50% { background-color: #A00; box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0 -1px 7px 1px, inset #441313 0 -1px 9px, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5) 0 2px 0;}
    to { background-color: #F00; }
}
@-ms-keyframes blinkRed {
    from { background-color: #F00; }
    50% { background-color: #A00; box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0 -1px 7px 1px, inset #441313 0 -1px 9px, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5) 0 2px 0;}
    to { background-color: #F00; }
}
@-o-keyframes blinkRed {
    from { background-color: #F00; }
    50% { background-color: #A00; box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0 -1px 7px 1px, inset #441313 0 -1px 9px, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5) 0 2px 0;}
    to { background-color: #F00; }
}
@keyframes blinkRed {
    from { background-color: #F00; }
    50% { background-color: #A00; box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0 -1px 7px 1px, inset #441313 0 -1px 9px, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5) 0 2px 0;}
    to { background-color: #F00; }
}
.textContainer {
    text-align: center;
}
.center {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="row"></div>

<div class="textContainer">
  <h1 class="center" style="color:Black; font-size: 3.5vw;">Welcome to <span id="h5">Comet 1.1</span></h1>

  <div class="led-box">
    <div class="led-red"></div>
    <p>Request Pending</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="center" style="color:Black; font-size: 3.5vw;">Welcome to <span id="h5">Comet 1.1</span></h1>
   
    <div class="led-box">
        <div class="led-red"></div>
        <p>Request Pending</p>
    </div>
</div>

.container { display: flex; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
.container{
     display: flex;
   }
```

```html
<div class="container">

    <h1 class="center" style="color:Black; font-size: 3.5vw;">Welcome to <span id="h5">Comet 1.1</span></h1>
       
    <div class="led-box">
        <div class="led-red"></div>
        <p>Request Pending</p>
    </div>
</div>
```